# Rails go-live checklist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

We're going to go live with our Rails 3.1 app shortly. What should we make sure we have incorporated from the start before we get a load of users and data?

We have:

- A passing test suite
- Heroku add-ons SSL, custom domains, logging,
  backups on their shared database (celadon stack)
- A staging site
- HireFire to scale workers Devise and cancan authorisation /
  authentication
- acts_as_audited
- S3 being used for assets
- delayed_job for background tasks
- decent refactored code

Obviously this question is best asked at the start of a project, not near the end, but have you regretted not including something from launch?

Comment: This is off-topic at Stack Overflow, and not constructive to boot. There is no way to usefully answer this as you can use everything in that list and still write a broken app full of security holes. The list is also pretty meaningless, as it will vary wildly from app to app. Most of the things there aren't applicable to most applications.

Comment: I thought someone would say that. Oh well.

Comment: what about caching, mail delivery, exception notifications?